# How to get to know whether current url it's in http or https in php/laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Is there anyone know how to achieve this? , 
if possible i don't want the full url , 
i just want to get whether it's http or https in laravel or php .

Answer (score 2):

use **parse_url()**

Parse a URL and return its components

```
    $url = 'http://username:password@hostname:9090/path?arg=value#anchor';

    echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_SCHEME);

    // var_dump(parse_url($url)); it will return all components .
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
http
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Laravels built in Request [secure()](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_secure) method.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like so in php:

```
if ((!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off') || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) {

    return true; 
}
```

You can wrap it in a function like so:

```
function requestIsHTTPS(){
    if ((!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off') || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) {

        return true; 
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: if for example i want to redirect to https if the current request is in http , how do i do it inside application? (not nginx)